# Interactive secure shell in Golang not capturing all keyboard

Tags: shell, go, ssh

I am trying to start an interactive SSH session with a remote computer using Golang. I was able to get that without any problems, but the pseudo terminal doesn't seem to be capturing all of the keyboard i/o correctly.

For example, if I run a regular SSH command like,

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/some-key.pem username@1.1.1.1
```

I can exit with a simple `Ctrl+d`, but for some reason when I run the interactive shell started with Golang it's not working and only prints the actual key characters `^D`. Same goes for trying to use the arrow keys. If I run a `Ctrl+c` it exits the original Golang process and kills the interactive shell rather than executing on the remote machine.

Below is my code for setting up the shell,

```
func StartInteractiveShell(sshConfig *ssh.ClientConfig, network string, host string, port string) error {
    var (
        session *ssh.Session
        conn    *ssh.Client
        err     error
    )    
    if conn, err = getSshConnection(sshConfig, network, host, port); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to dial: %s", err)
        return err   
    }

    if session, err = getSshSession(conn); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to create session: %s", err)
        return err
    }
    defer session.Close()

    if err = setupPty(session); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to set up pseudo terminal: %s", err)
        return err
    }

    session.Stdout = os.Stdout
    session.Stdin  = os.Stdin
    session.Stderr = os.Stderr

    if err = session.Shell(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to start interactive shell: %s", err)
        return err
    }
    return session.Wait()
}

func getSshConnection(config *ssh.ClientConfig, network string, host string, port string) (*ssh.Client, error) {
    addr := host + ":" + port
    return ssh.Dial(network, addr, config)
}

func getSshSession(clientConnection *ssh.Client) (*ssh.Session, error) {
    return clientConnection.NewSession()
}

// pty = pseudo terminal
func setupPty(session *ssh.Session) error {
    modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
        ssh.ECHO:          0,     // disable echoing
        ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400, // input speed = 14.4kbaud
        ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400, // output speed = 14.4kbaud
    }

    if err := session.RequestPty("xterm", 80, 40, modes); err != nil {
        session.Close()
        fmt.Printf("request for pseudo terminal failed: %s", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Am I missing something there?

Comment: Perhaps you need to capture the signals in your Go program and send them over to the remote host using `ssh.Session`'s method [`func (*Session) Signal`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session.Signal).

Comment: @abhink are you thinking that I should listen for signals using something like `signal.Notify` and then send those the session using `session.Signal(some-signal)`?

Comment: Yes. When you hit `Ctrl-C`, it's being interpreted by the Go program. You might have to pass it over to the ssh session.

Comment: There is also the possibility that your terminal and/or shell settings interrupts CTRL characters differently.  My iterm2 + VIM + Tmux requires special options to get VTRL characters shared through all tmux and non-tmux sessions.

Comment: I was actually able to accomplish this by using the `os/exec` package and running `exec.Command(SSH_COMMAND_HERE)` and everything worked. I did have some success with catching the control signals and forwarding to the session, but it quickly became quite tedious to handle all of the desired signals.